# List array of post's categories inside loop

Tags: arrays, wordpress, loops, foreach, categories

I have list of posts displayed as a grid, and **I need each post to list its own categories, separated by commas.** I have a functional code, but it only lists one category.

Current code:

```
   <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'category_name' => 'category')); 

   while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php $category = get_the_category();
          echo '<figure data-groups='. esc_attr('["'.$category[0]->slug.'"]').'>';
          echo'<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url ('medium').'"/>';
          </figure>';?>
       <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Which outputs `<figure data-groups='["category1"]>`

What I need is `<figure data-groups='["category1","category2","category3"]>`

I did see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773384/wordpress-how-to-add-commas-in-this-get-the-category-function), but I am unable to get this working without errors that read "Cannot use object of type WP_Term as array."
Here's my attempt that produced the error:

```
  $categories = get_the_category();
    $category_names = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category)
    {
        $category_names[] = $category->cat_name;
    }
    echo implode(', ', $category_names);

          echo '<figure class="gallery-photo" data-groups='. esc_attr('["all","'.$category_names.'"]').'>';
```

I'm guessing I will have to use a function of some kind. Any help I can get is much appreciated!
**EDIT - final code:**

```
 <?php $the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'category_name' => 'category')); 
 while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();

    $categories = get_the_category();
    $category_names = array();
    foreach ($categories as $category){
      $category_names[] = $category->slug; }
      $category_list = implode("\",\"",  $category_names);

    echo '<figure data-groups='. esc_attr('["'.$category_list.'"]').'>';
          echo'<img src="'.wp_get_attachment_url ('medium').'"/>';
          </figure>'; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the code you copied, `$category_names` is an array. You can't `echo` an array the way you did it, to get this output:

```
<figure data-groups='["category1","category2","category3"]'>
```

try:

```
echo "<figure data-groups='[ " . "\"" . implode( "\",\"", $category_names ) . "\"" . " ]'>";
// outputs
// <figure data-groups='[ "sample","Uncategorised" ]'>
```

Comment: Thanks, this really helped! I've included my updated code above, with some formatting adjustments. The php echo did not like the brackets and parentheses.